# Phrasal Usage of called on

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

Consider the sentence: "America's respected Institute of Medicine called *for/on* nurses to play a greater role in primary care."

Which is more appropriate *on* or *for*?

Comment: *for* in conventional English. *upon* may be already archaic. Certainly not *on*.

Answer (score 3):

Which is appropriate depends on the meaning that is to be conveyed.

If you *call **on** nurses to play a greater role in primary care*, you are making a direct appeal to the nurses to do so.

If you *call **for** nurses to play a greater role in primary care*, you are not necessarily appealing directly to the nurses. You could be making a general appeal that whoever is responsible for the deployment of nurses should increase their role in primary care.

Answer (score 2):

Different prepositions alter the sense of the sentence. Either might be appropriate, but it depends on what the Institute of Medicine is actually doing.

With the verb *call* meaning "appeal", the preposition *on* specifies who is being addressed; *for* specifies the object of the address. Here, the Institute of Medicine thinks that nurses should do more in primary care, but who are they addressing that thought to?

Is the Institute of Medicine addressing the nurses themselves (use *on*) or someone else including nobody in particular (use *for*)?